# Как объединить 3 кода получения АПИ в один?

Tags: php, api

Здравствуйте. Есть 3 кода

1)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=ABA&destination=MOW&limit=1&token=*******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: ******"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$products=json_decode($response,true);    
?>

<?php if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
  foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
    echo ($data[0]['price']);
    foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
    }
  }
}
?>
```

2)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=ABA&destination=AER&limit=1&*******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *******"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$products=json_decode($response,true);
?>

<?php if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
  foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
    echo ($data[0]['price']);
    foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
    }
  }
}
?>
```

3)

```
  <?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=ABA&destination=HKT&limit=1&token=********");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: ********"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$products=json_decode($response,true);
?>

<?php if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
  foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
    echo ($data[0]['price']);
    foreach ($data as $destination => $row) {
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Различаются эти коды вот этой строчкой
http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/cheap?origin=ABA&destination=**HKT**&limit=1&token=*********

Если 3 кода разместить на одной странице, то сработает только первый код, второй и третий не покажут никаких значений. Помогите пожалуйста или объединить в один код, чтобы скрипты выполнялись не мешая друг другу или не объединяя чтобы выполнялись раздельно так же не мешая друг другу. Спасибо

Comment: В функциях нет прерывания скрипта. С чего Вы взяли, что первый кусок кода не даст выполниться другим? Другой вопрос, что зачем дублировать код, если можно все оформить одной функцией, но это ладно

Comment: @AntonShchyrov пробую коды поставить на одну страницу и все 3 кода дают результат выполненный от первого. а мне нужно чтобы давали каждый свой результат.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Как их прервать?

Comment: Где вы используете `$replace_value`? Если это не важно для вопроса, то лучше удалить этот кусок. Вы говорите что даже `var_dump` возвращает одинаковый response?

Comment: @Torv Само Апи отдает разные значения, а вот при выводе значения почему то одинаковые

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае больше подходит [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php), попробуйте его использовать как описано например [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362362/file-get-contents-from-multiple-url/21362749#21362749).

Ошибка в данном случае в том, что `$key` это destination, как я понимаю, а `$data`, содержит в себе массив, не совсем с теми данными которые вы ожидаете, вот его var_dump:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(20400)
    ["airline"]=>
    string(2) "S7"
    ["flight_number"]=>
    int(3034)
    ["departure_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-01-28T09:10:00Z"
    ["return_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-02-03T16:20:00Z"
    ["expires_at"]=>
    string(20) "2017-12-17T05:55:26Z"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(6) {
    ["price"]=>
    int(25200)
    ["airline"]=>
    string(2) "S7"
    ["flight_number"]=>
    int(3034)
    ["departure_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-01-28T09:10:00Z"
    ["return_at"]=>
    string(20) "2018-02-03T05:20:00Z"
    ["expires_at"]=>
    string(20) "2017-12-17T05:55:26Z"
  }
}
```

Другими словами, вам нужен еще один цикл. Поэкспереминтировать с вашими данными вы можете например [здесь](https://3v4l.org/9vIDN).

Для вывода цены можно использовать код вида:

```
foreach ($products['data'] as $destination => $data) {
    foreach ($data as $dataKey => $dataValue) {
        echo $dataValue['price'].PHP_EOL;
    }
  }
```

Если же вам нужна только первая запись, то можно использовать код вида:

```
foreach ($products['data'] as $destination => $data) {
    $iNeedOnlyThisValue = array_shift($data); //После этого в дате не будет одного значения
    echo $iNeedOnlyThisValue['price'].PHP_EOL;
  }
```

Но в данном случае стоит быть аккуратным с дальнейшим использованием данных.

P.S. Я бы крайне рекомендовал вам прочитать [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339038/). Надеюсь вы используете xdebug.

Comment: Я благодарен Вам и за совет в первом сообщении и за "Сарказм" во втором. Но если бы я мог это сам исправить, я бы не обращался за Помощью. С уважением.

Comment: @Arcadiy если вы про статью, то это нисколько не сарказм, если бы вы вдумчиво дебажили свой код, то у вас не возникло бы этого вопроса, т.к. вы сразу бы поняли в чем тут дело, и при этом вы затратили бы куда меньше часа.

Comment: @Arcadiy Я не уточнил, так вы решили проблему?

Comment: Нет. Заменил в кодах значение на вот это $data[$key]['price']  это если не объединять, вообще даже в первом коде данные не выводятся.

Comment: @Arcadiy в таком случае ваше возмущение понятно, сейчас подумаем еще.

Comment: я не возмущаюсь. Я пытаюсь увидеть истину.

Comment: @Arcadiy изменил ответ

Comment: Выдает несколько значений с одного кода, а нужно одно первое с каждого кода.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70291/discussion-between-torv-and-arcadiy).